# Is there a way to change the Button.addActionListener behaviour?

Tags: codenameone

If I use the .addActionListener on a button the button fires action "onRelease". Is there a simple way to change that behaviour to "onPress"?

I found a workaround by overriding the pointerPressed method. That works for what I want to achieve, but is that a proper way to go?

```
Button button1 = new Button("LEFT"){
            @Override
            public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {                                      
                super.pointerPress(x, y);
                m.play();               
                showLeftForm();             
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason all frameworks fire on release and not on press.

If you do the latter the release event will trigger as you're transitioning to the new form and could cause problems. E.g. a `repaint()` during screen transition might cause artifacts in some OS/transition combinations etc.

Having said that you can use pointer pressed listener if you wish although I would recommend against it.